# Ordenamiento de un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un ejercicio de programación en javascript de ordenamiento de arreglos usando .sort(), pero no he dado con la solución. A continuación mi codigo:

```js
   
function fixIt(my_list) {

    let new_list = [];
    if (my_list.length % 2) { 
        for (let item of my_list) {
            for (let element of item) {
                new_list = new_list.push(element);
            }
        }
    } else {
        new_list = my_list.flat();
    }

    new_list.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (x % 5 === y % 5) {
            return x - y
        } else {
            return x % 5 - y % 5
        }
    })
    return new_list
}
arr = [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 6 ] ]; 
arr2 = [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 12, 32, 89 ], [ 0 ] ]

console.log(fixIt(arr));
console.log(fixIt(arr2));
```

La salida de consola para **arr** debe ser:

> [4,3,2,6]

Pero me lanza:

> [ 6, 2, 3, 4 ]

También la salida de **arr2** debería ser:

> [89,4,3,32,12,0,-1]

Pero me da el error:

> new_list.push is not a function.

Comment: agrega cual el criterio de ordenamiento, como los queres ordenar?

Answer (score 1):

Aca te dejo una version modificada que te da el resultado esperado:

```js
function fixIt(my_list) {
    
      let new_list = [];
      if (my_list.length % 2) { 
          for (let item of my_list) {
              for (let element of item) {
                // new_list = new_list.push(element) aca decis que new_list es igual a lo que devuelve push, y eso que devuelve es un numero
                // que representa la nueva longitud del array, por lo que en la siguiente iteracion new_list es un numero y push() no es una funcion de numeros
                // deberias hacer simplemente:
                new_list.push(element);
              }
          }
      } else {
          new_list = my_list.flat();
      }
    
      new_list.sort(function (x, y) {
          // me di cuenta que el valor esperado era igual al erroneo que te dio a vos, pero invertido. Asi que inverti las x e y a partir de esta linea
          if (y % 5 === x % 5) {
              return y - x
          } else {
              return y % 5 - x % 5
          }
      })
      return new_list
    }
    
    arr = [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 6 ] ]; 
    arr2 = [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 12, 32, 89 ], [ 0 ] ]
    
    console.log(fixIt(arr));
    console.log(fixIt(arr2));
```

quizás si colocas el criterio de ordenamiento que buscas podríamos darte una respuesta más completa. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Si prestas atención los arreglos se están ordenando bien, solo que en sentido opuesto. Solo tienes que intercambiar de lugares `x` e `y`.

En cuanto al error, se produce porque estás agregando un elemento al arreglo con `push` y a la vez estableces `new_list` al valor que devuelve la función.

La asignación está demás.

Por cierto, puedes reemplazar la primera mitad del código por `my_list.flat` pasando la profundidad hasta la que quieras. Por ejemplo 10 podría ser suficiente.

El código quedaría así:

```js
function fixIt(my_list) {

    let new_list = my_list.flat(10)

    new_list.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (x % 5 === y % 5) {
            return y - x
        } else {
            return y % 5 - x % 5
        }
    })
    return new_list
}
arr = [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 6 ] ]; 
arr2 = [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 12, 32, 89 ], [ 0 ] ]

console.log(fixIt(arr));
console.log(fixIt(arr2));
```